# Create and store user defined form templates

Tags: objective-c, data-storage

I'm relatively new to IOS programming in Xcode, so I was hoping to get a little help here. 
At the moment, I'm working on an application that gives the users the ability to create their own form templates. (swipe controls on the screen and save this)

I was wondering how this can be technically done. Are there any tutorials where I can find a similar example? (how to store data, how to store which controls were added to the template)

At the moment there is nog backend (data must be stored locally), but there will be one in the future.